# Is "connection.Close()" the best or safest way to close an SQL connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been using

```
connection.Close();
```

But this is my first project in .NET and I'm not sure if I'm closing it correctly.

I don't want my website to instantly die after putting it out on real hosting.

Usually I do it this way:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.Connection = conn;

    // <some code>

    conn.Open();
    / <some code>
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: It's OK your code,  but using is more clearly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should place the connection in a using statement;

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection)
{
  connection.Open();
  ...other code using it here.
}
```

The using statement ensures that the SqlConnection is disposed when you are done with it.  In your scenario (depending on where you put the close method), if an exception is closed, it will never reach the Close() method and the connection will stay open.

Even better is that since you are building a website.  There should be a method on the Request object (which should be available) called RegisterForDispose.  This will automatically Dispose of the connection (which closes it) when the request ends. You can use it like this:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection();
Request.RegisterForDispose(connection);
```

Both accomplish the same thing in the end, but the second allows for more flexibility.

Comment: Edited my posted. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, so in your code if an exception is thrown somewhere, the connection will not close.  It will eventually as the Garbage Collector will do it at some time, but it's always better to ensure that you do it either throw a try/finally or a using statement.

Comment: +1 The using block guarantees lifetime and proper disposal of the connection, and its underlying streams and event loops. ,Close() is fine so long as you manage it properly through Try-Finally blocks. At procedural level the connection variable will go out of scope after the return anyway.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I get it now. Seems like it was a good choice to ask here, couldn't find much in google beside some old posts from 2005 or something x_ x

Comment: @Harugawa, glad I could help.  Funny enough I was working on a blog article that talks about using statements on websites.  I'll post it here when I'm done in case you want to take a look.

Comment: @Kevin Surely, post link here or something when you done :)

Comment: Here is the post I was referring to: http://structuredsight.com/2016/02/29/pushing-data/

Answer (score 2):

Do what Kevin said and put your .Open() call inside the using block:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("my sql command here", conn);

    conn.Open();

    cmd.(whatever method you are using)
}
```